# Delphi 2010 IDE problem when adding button to form?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-2010

I just started having issues with my Delphi 2010 IDE. If I drop any of the Standard Controls onto a form, "**StdCtrls**" does not get added to the uses clause. In fact the uses clause does not get updated if I drop **any controls** on the form.

I've rebooted my machine and it still does not work. How can I get this to work like it's supposed to?

Comment: Are you sure about this? because this behavior is normal, the units are added when you save the changes or invoke the code completion pressing Ctrl-Space.

Comment: I called Embarcedero today a talked with Christopher in support. I verified that the uses clause does not get updated just by adding components to the form. You have to hit Ctrl-Space. Now, I know I'm only 52 years old and I could have sworn this used to automatically work. Does this mean I'm already starting to loose it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The uses list is only updated when you save or compile the unit.